# 2sxc Permissions.UserMayEditContent not available anymore

Tags: 2sxc

Since the latest 2sxc version 10.20+ the property `Permissions.UserMayEditContent` isn't available anymore. Error message: *The name 'Permissions' does not exist in the current context..*.

I have implemented the use of latest features of 2sxc 10.20+ by entering `@inherits ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.RazorComponent` as first line into the razor file as explained [here](https://docs.2sxc.org/how-to/dotnet-razor-csharp-overview.html).

The docs.2sxc.org Spec still contains an example [here](https://docs.2sxc.org/specs/js/commands.html?q=UserMayEditContent). How should this be implemented with the latest 2sxc DNN Module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new property is `Edit.Enabled`. Found it after long searching as a comment within the 2sxc repository and then within the docs [here](https://docs.2sxc.org/how-to/razor/edit.html).

Comment: thx for finding the answer and sorry about the breaking change. Edit.Enabled has been around for about 2 years and we didn't think people would be using the old command. sorry :(. best mark this question as answered.

Comment: The example within the documentation [here](https://docs.2sxc.org/specs/js/commands.html) still uses `UserMayEditContent`, same your apps like _app-blog_. That made it tricky :) Thanks @iJungleBoy for the very useful new documentation.

Comment: thanks! just fixed it. We'll also make sure that the old command still works if you're working in the "old" mode which doesn't use @inherits... RazorComponent